# Get String Before And After Character Then Set Them As a Variable Python

Tags: python, string, variables, python-2.7

If I want to get two string separated by a character then set them as a variable how would I go about doing that?

An example:

```
john:doe
```

I want to set "john" to variable fname, and "doe" to variable lname.  I would want my outcome of the script to look like the following:

```
    print  fname
    john
    print lname
    doe
```

All help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Split the string by `:` and unpack the results:

```
>>> s = "john:doe"
>>> s.split(':')
['john', 'doe']
>>> fname, lname = s.split(':')
>>> fname
'john'
>>> lname
'doe'
```